# Getting distance between 2 postcodes using Google Maps in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

This topic has been brought up a few times - but I've tried every option in  Google Sheets but it keeps returning "Imported Content is empty" on my function

The code I'm using is below (where G23 & H23 are postcodes)

`=importxml("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin="&G23&"&destination="&H23&"&sensor=false&alternatives=false&key=MYKEY","//leg/duration/value")`

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome. One of the issues here is the use of "postcodes" rather than specific locations. You mentioned that the topic had been brought up a few times - please include these references in your question so we avoid duplicated research. [Calculate (road travel) distance between postcodes/zipcodes python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44176381/1330560) and [Google maps - Postcode plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3495006/1330560) are two references that i found, but neither has anything as uncomplicated as an `importxml` function. Would you please give a reference for that function.